# spritekit, a node collide two nodes at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

There is a node collide where there are two nodes at the same time, but in my `Didbegincontact` I set function to execute both contacts, but I only need one to work. Why doesn't the other one work?

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code ?

Comment: You need to differentiate between objects in the touchesBegan method. You can do that either by naming an object and checking the object's name when touched or by using categoryBitMask in physics bodies.